# Insert Result Query Into Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I have problem with an insert query in Postgresql.

I have query like this :

```
select *
from (
  select *,
      row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as row_number
  from lookup_temp
     ) as rows
where row_number = 1
```

and I want to insert the result to table `lookup_temp`.
How can I do this?

Comment: You want to insert into the table you are selecting from in the sub query?

Comment: INSERT INTO lookup_temp(col1, col2, etc.) SELECT _rest_of_select_statement;

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are trying to insert `lookup_temp` with  only one row of each `id` repeating in your *select* (because of using this `select *,row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as row_numberfrom lookup_temp`) to the same table `lookup_temp`. if yes the below query is enough for you.

```
delete from lookup_temp where ctid in (
  select ctid from (
                  select ctid,
                  row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as row_number
                  from lookup_temp
                 ) as rows
  where row_number <> 1)
```

[**ctid**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-system-columns.html)

> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that
>   although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly,
>   a row's ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL.
>   Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. The OID, or
>   even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify
>   logical rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an INSERT from SELECT to get the result into the lookup_temp table

```
INSERT into lookup_temp (specify your columns) VALUES
 (
  select *
  from (
       select *,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as row_number
       from lookup_temp
       ) as rows
  where row_number = 1
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be simpler with `distinct on`

```
insert into lookup_temp
select distinct on (id) *
from lookup_temp
```

If you are inserting into another table specify the columns

```
insert into another_table (id, c1, c2...)
select distinct on (id) id, c1, c2...
from lookup_temp
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

--Just do it this way. It should work fine

```
select *
INTO lookup_temp
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as row_number
    from lookup_temp
) as rows
where row_number = 1
```

Comment: Please provide a small explanation of how this code solves the problem.